# Can i put null to Integer if stream api not found a wanted id in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stream

I need to put null variable if stream api cannot find my filter variable in java.

```
Integer ingredientId = ingredients.stream().filter(medicine -> medicine.getId() == id)
                .mapToInt(medicine -> medicine.getId()).max().orElseThrow();
```

Comment: does method `getId()` return an `int` or an `Integer`? If it returns an `Integer`: is it guaranteed to not return `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use orElse instead of orElseThrow

```
int ingredientId = ingredients.stream()
                      .filter(medicine -> medicine.getId() == id)
                      .mapToInt(medicine -> medicine.getId())
                      .max()
                      .orElse(-1);
```

You cannot get NULL because max() returns an OptionalInt and it contains an primitive int.

So orElse could return a value that indicates that nothing was found.

Comment: Oh yes. I'm sorry. Check my answer

Comment: Notice that this might throw sneaky `Exception`s if `medicine.getId()` returns a `null` (this, of course, only holds true if the return-type of `getId` is `Integer`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mapToInt()` if you want a potential `null` result value.

```java
Integer ingredientId = ingredients.stream().filter(medicine -> medicine.getId() == id)
        .map(Ingredient::getId).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(null);
```

Since you `filter(getId() == id)`, the result of `max(getId())` is either `id` or "not found", so you can actually re-write the code to use `findAny()` instead of `max()`.

```java
Integer ingredientId = ingredients.stream().filter(medicine -> medicine.getId() == id)
        .findAny().map(Ingredient::getId).orElse(null);
```